# sql query using timestamp returns nothing

Tags: sql, sql-timestamp

I have a SQL table with a column `create_date` of type `timestamp`. I want to perform a query on the table that looks like this:

```
select * 
from table 
where create_date = '2022-11-17 13:42:42.309'
```

This should return the row with id=6. But when I execute this query it returns 0 results.

I tried casting the string to timestamp but that also doesn't work. I also tried adding the '+0000' to the string but that also does nothing.

This is what the table looks like:

[image]

Comment: Missing the `T` ? `select * from table where create_date='2022-11-17T13:42:42.309+0000'`

Comment: What kind of database is it?

Comment: How often is an object created? Do you really need milliseconds to distinguish between products?

Comment: I tried with the T, also doesn't work.

Comment: it's a spark sql. the milliseconds are not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution,the miliseconds i received had 6 digits, but the value stored in the server is 3 digits. so by removing the miliseconds the problem was solved